# Merging two different files with conditions

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, perl

I have two different files as shown below.

Content of `a.txt`:

```
HDR|1||||||||||               
DTL|@|||||||||||             
TLR|||||||||||||              
HDR|1||||||||||||            
DTL|||||||||||||              
TLR|||||||||||||
```

Content of `b.txt`:

```
HDR|2||||||||||  
DTL|||||||||||||
TLR|||||||||||||
HDR|2|||||||||||| 
DTL|last||||||||||||
TLR|||||||||||||
```

Here I have to take out all the lines till 1st "TLR" in a.txt and b.txt and merge into 1.txt
,same way take out all the lines After 1st "TLR" in a.txt and b.txt and merge into 2.txt

output should be:

Content of `1.txt`:

```
HDR|1|||||||||| 
DTL|@||||||||||| 
TLR|||||||||||||
HDR|2|||||||||| 
DTL|||||||||||| 
TLR|||||||||||||
```

Content of `2.txt`:

```
HDR|1|||||||||| 
DTL|||||||||||| 
TLR|||||||||||||
HDR|2|||||||||| 
DTL|last||||||||||| 
TLR|||||||||||||
```

How can we accomplish this using UNIX Script?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
sed -ne '1,/^TLR/p' a.txt > 1.txt
sed -ne '1,/^TLR/p' b.txt >> 1.txt
sed -e '1,/^TLR/d' a.txt > 2.txt
sed -e '1,/^TLR/d' b.txt >> 2.txt
```

That is:

- *Print the lines* from `a.txt` until matching `/^TLR/` and *create* `1.txt`
- *Print the lines* from `b.txt` until matching `/^TLR/` and *append to* `1.txt`
- *Drop the lines* from `a.txt` until matching `/^TLR/` and *create* `2.txt`
- *Drop the lines* from `b.txt` until matching `/^TLR/` and *append to* `2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could run the same command twice on the two different files:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if $a<1; $a++ if /TLR/; ' a.txt > 1.txt
$ perl -ne 'print if $a<1; $a++ if /TLR/; ' b.txt >> 1.txt
```

and

```
$ perl -ne 'print if $a>=1; $a++ if /TLR/; ' a.txt > 2.txt
$ perl -ne 'print if $a>=1; $a++ if /TLR/; ' b.txt >> 2.txt
```

These simple scriptlets will add 1 to the value of the variable `$a` if the current line contains `TLR`. They then check the value of `$a` to decide if this line should be printed or not.

You can combine both operations into one command with:

```
$ perl -e '
  foreach my $file(@ARGV){
    open(my $fh,"$file"); $a=0;
    while(<$fh>){
     $a<1 ? (push @{$lines{1}},$_) : (push @{$lines{2}},$_); $a++ if /TLR/}} 
  END{open(my $fh,">","1.txt"); print $fh @{$lines{1}}; 
      open(my $fh,">","2.txt"); print $fh @{$lines{2}};}' a.txt b.txt
```